# Querying elements in Xpath using C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I'm learning Xpath with the help of some documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/308333/how-to-query-xml-with-an-xpath-expression-by-using-visual-c) and am stuck with a particilar query. In the Following XML Im trying to print out the `<value>` of the `<OwnerName>` for the books which the price is > 10 and I used the following Xpath Query to do so

```
    strExpression = "/bookstore/book/name/value[../price>10.00]";

    NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);

    Console.WriteLine("Names of expensive books owners:");

    while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Owner Name: {0}", NodeIter.Current.Value);
    };


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
<bookstore>
   <book genre="autobiography">
      <OwnerName>
         <value>Alex dan</value>
      </OwnerName>
      <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
      <author>
         <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
         <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
      </author>
      <price>8.99</price>
   </book>
   <book genre="novel">
      <OwnerName>
         <value>Pam Sanderson</value>
      </OwnerName>
      <title>The Confidence Man</title>
      <author>
         <first-name>Herman</first-name>
         <last-name>Melville</last-name>
      </author>
      <price>11.99</price>
   </book>
   <book genre="philosophy">
      <OwnerName>
         <value>Rogger Mark</value>
      </OwnerName>
      <title>The Gorgias</title>
      <author>
         <name>Plato</name>
      </author>
      <price>9.99</price>
   </book>
</bookstore>
```

what am I doing wrong here would really appreciate some help

Comment: Do be aware that you a learning a version of XPath that is 20 years old and long superseded. Microsoft have not kept up to date with changes in the XML world. However, it doesn't affect this example.

Comment: whats the updated one michael ? anydocumentation:)

Comment: The current version of XPath is 3.1. In between is XPath 2.0. Searching for either will find masses of information - more on 2.0 because it's been around for longer. A lot depends on what kind of information you like to read: personally, I go straight to the W3C specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write :

```
/bookstore/book/name/value[../price>10.00]
```

Why it doesn't work :

- Missing `/` at the beginning of your XPath expression (look anywhere)
- You're calling `name` element instead of `ownername` element
- Missing one `..` (parent operator) since you want to use `/price` (child of `book` not `ownername`)
- Missing `[]` (predicate) to test the `book` node or the `price` node

So to sum, to fix your XPath (following your logic) you could have 2 syntaxes :

```
//bookstore/book/ownername/value[../../price[.>10]]
//bookstore/book/ownername/value[../..[price>10]]
```

Other options (more or less consuming) :

```
//value[../..[price>10]]
//value[ancestor::book[1][price>10]]
//price[.>10]/preceding::value[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's necessary to change the XPath expression.

Instead of

```
strExpression = "/bookstore/book/name/value[../price>10.00]";
```

use

```
strExpression = "/bookstore/book[price>10.00]/OwnerName/value";
```